# convert date to specific timezone iOS swift

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my app i want to convert NSDate to specific time zone.The issue is that i am not able to convert it.

Code

```
let calender = NSDateComponents()
calender.year = 2017
calender.month = 02
calender.day =  17
let  calenderCurrentDate = NSCalendar(identifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)?.dateFromComponents(calender)
```

Here if i print the `calenderCurrentDate` i am getting my local date not the specified timezone's date.Even though i am specifying the day as 17, but while printing i am still getting 16.

Comment: Check. http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-nsdate-in-swift/

Comment: You want to convert date in which timezone?